# plot r two categorical variables

Tags: r, plot

I am using below command to plot two categorical variables in R

gender has 2 levels and Income has 9 levels.

```
spineplot(main$Gender,main$Income, xlab="Gender", ylab="Income levels: 1 is lowest",xaxlabels=c("Male","Female"))
```

It produces chart like below [image]

1. How can i plot this chart in color?
2. How can i show % of each income level within each box? for example female income level 1 has 21% of data. How can i show `21%` within the dark colored area?

################update 1

Adding reproducible example

```
fail <- factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,
                 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,2,2,2,2),
               levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("male", "female"))
gender <- factor(rep(c(1:9),3))
spineplot(fail,gender)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to the interesting solution of @rawr is:

```
fail <- factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,
                 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,2,2,2,2),
               levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("male", "female"))
gender <- factor(rep(c(1:9),3))

mypalette <- colorRampPalette(c("lightblue","darkblue"))
tbl <- spineplot(fail, gender, xlab="Gender", ylab="Income levels: 1 is lowest",
     xaxlabels=c("Male","Female"), col=mypalette(nlevels(gender)) )
print(tbl)

#        Income levels: 1 is lowest
# Gender   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# male   2 1 2 1 3 2 2 2 1
# female 1 2 1 2 0 1 1 1 2

print.perc <- function(k, tbl, ndigits=2, str.pct="%") {
   # These lines of codes are the same used by from spineplot
   # for the calculation of the x-position of the stacked bars
   nx <- nrow(tbl)
   off <- 0.02
   xat <- c(0, cumsum(prop.table(margin.table(tbl, 1)) + off))
   posx <- (xat[1L:nx] + xat[2L:(nx + 1L)] - off)/2
   # Proportions by row (gender)       
   ptbl <- prop.table(tbl,1)
   # Define labels as strings with a given format
   lbl <- paste(format(round(100*ptbl[k,], ndigits), nsmall=ndigits), str.pct, sep="")
   # Print labels
   # cumsum(ptbl[k,])-ptbl[k,]/2 is the vector of y-positions
   # for the centers of each stacked bar
   text(posx[k], cumsum(ptbl[k,])-ptbl[k,]/2, lbl)
}

# Print income levels for males and females
strsPct <- c("%","%")
for (k in 1:nrow(tbl)) print.perc(k, tbl, ndigits=2, str.pct=strsPct[k])
```

[image]

Hope it can help you.

Comment: would it be possible to write few explanations about your print.perc function? it will enable me to apply your solution to my data

Comment: also, would it be possible to show how to plot in shades of a single color?

Comment: anyway to get percentages in bold ?

Comment: aalso please let me know how to find color keywords such aslightblue darkblue

Comment: Add `font=2` in `text` for bold face. For color keywords type `colors()` in the command prompt.

Comment: is there a way to show % for only 1 column? thanks in advance

Comment: @user2543622 See the last change to my answer. You can add or delete `%` simply modifying the content of the `strsPct` vector.

Answer (score 4):

I think it may be easier to do this with a `barplot` since `spineplot` doesn't return anything useful.

The default would be the following, but you can adjust the widths of the bars to some other variable (you can see the x-axis coordinates are returned):

```
par(mfrow = 1:2)
(barplot(table(gender, fail)))
# [1] 0.7 1.9
(barplot(table(gender, fail), width = table(fail)))
# [1] 10.7 26.9
```

[image]

With some final touches we get

```
tbl <- table(gender, fail)
prp <- prop.table(tbl, 2L)
yat <- prp / 2 + apply(rbind(0, prp[-nrow(prp), ]), 2L, cumsum)

bp <- barplot(prp, width = table(fail), axes = FALSE, col = rainbow(nrow(prp)))

axis(2L, at = yat[, 1L], labels = levels(gender), lwd = 0)
axis(4L)

text(rep(bp, each = nrow(prp)), yat, sprintf('%0.f%%', prp * 100), col = 0)
```

[image]

Compare to

```
spineplot(fail, gender, col = rainbow(nlevels(gender)))
```

[image]

Comment: instead of rainbow, would it be possible to get shades of green or blue?

Comment: @user2543622 yes although it depends on what you mean by shade. for example, you could take one color and apply different amounts of transparency `col = Vectorize(adjustcolor)('green4', alpha.f = seq(.3, 1, length.out = nrow(prp)))` or two or more fully-transparent colors with shades between them `col = colorRampPalette(c('limegreen', 'darkgreen'))(nrow(prp))`